# Rails 3 has_one/has_many question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, data-modeling

I am writing an application that contains a database with several tables and joining tables and so forth... the two I am working with currently (and am stumped on) are my pages table and my templates table.

Now a page can contain only one template, but a template can have many pages.

Model for Page:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :template
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :template
end
```

Model for Template:

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
end
```

When a user creates a page, I want them to be able to select a layout, but for some reason the select list is not showing up

HTML for show:

```
<%= form_for(@page) do |page| %>
  <% if @page.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@page.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this page from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @page.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= page.label "Page title" %><br />
    <%= page.text_field :slug %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= page.label :active %>?<br />
    <%= page.check_box :active %>
  </div>

    <%= page.fields_for :category do |cat| %>
        <%= cat.label :category %>
        <%= select :page, :category_id, Category.find(:all).collect{|c| [c.name, c.id] } %>
    <% end %>

    <%= page.fields_for :template do |temp| %>
        <%= temp.label :template %>
        <%= select :page, :template_id, Template.find(:all).collect{|t| [t.content, t.id] } %>
    <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any reasons why the last select wouldn't show up?

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Edit:

All I had to do to fix the problem was put the Model logic in my controller and then call that object in the view and it worked

Controller:

```
def new
    @page = Page.new
    @categories = Category.find(:all)
    @templates = Template.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @page }
    end
  end
```

View:

```
<div class="field">
        <%= page.label :template %>
        <%= page.select("template_id", @templates.collect { |t| [t.content, t.id] }, :include_blank => 'None') %>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

First page could "belongs to" template:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :template
end
```

And instead of:

```
<%= page.fields_for :template do |temp| %>
    <%= temp.label :template %>
    <%= select :page, :template_id, Template.find(:all).collect{|t| [t.content, t.id] } %>
<% end %>
```

I would use a simple collection_select:

```
<%= page.select("template_id", Template.all.collect {|t| [ t.contet, t.id ] }) %>
```

Comment: I am getting this error now: undefined method `all' for ActionView::Template:Class

Comment: I figured out my problem! I will put in the solution above